# Google Cloud Run - Executing background job with always-allocated CPU

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a web app and a background worker service running in Cloud Run.
The main app calls the background worker which is essentially just an `rq` worker wrapped in a thin Flask app to adhere to the runtime contract. The `rq` worker is spawned via `subprocess.Popen`.
I do not block the main thread with the `Popen` call, and return a response immediately. However, the instance still seems to die after 15 minutes of processing.

Per the documentation, it appears this workflow should be supported so long as there is some sort of CPU processing going on (it isn't exactly clear):

> If you want to support background activities in your Cloud Run service, set your Cloud Run service CPU to be always allocated so you can run background activities outside of requests and still have CPU access.

Another article says:

> Note that even if CPU is always allocated, Cloud Run autoscaling is still in effect, and may terminate container instances if they aren't needed to handle incoming traffic. An instance **will never stay idle for more than 15 minutes after processing a request** unless it is kept active using minimum instances.

This 15-minute limit seems to be what I'm encountering despite the CPU certainly not being "idle" in any sense of the word.

The particular background jobs I am spawning could potentially take 1 - 2 hours in some extreme cases, so blocking the main thread, not returning a response until completion, and increasing the request timeout would not work as maxes out at 1 hour (not to mention it's prone to error).

Is there a way to make this work without moving toward GKE or hacky Cloud Build workarounds?

EDIT - Some additional details

Worker service configuration:

- CPU is **always allocated**
- Maximum requests per container = 1
- Min instances 0
- Max instances 10

Here is the server that spawns the rq worker:

```py
import os
import subprocess

from flask import Flask, Response
from http import HTTPStatus

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    subprocess.Popen(["rq", "worker", "--burst", "--url", os.getenv("REDIS_URL"), "queue"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    return Response(status=HTTPStatus.OK)
```

The Dockerfile for which just runs the following command after setting things up:

```sh
gunicorn -w 1 --timeout 0 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app:app
```

The logs do not yield anything particularly useful because I never use `communicate()` or check the output of the `Popen` call to avoid blocking the main thread. I am left with just the gunicorn logs as a result, which isn't ideal:
[image: gunicorn logs]

Comment: Did you try setting the min instsance count? Or is this not an option as such a container that starts a background threat could come from scaling up?

Comment: Each container handles exactly one job and should then exit. It scales 1:1 per request so that there is effectively never queueing behavior with jobs -- they're all handled as they come in by a worker that is dynamically spun up. A minimum instance doesn't help in my case, I don't think.

Comment: Edit your question and show how the service is configured and the logs showing the startup and termination of the container.

Comment: I've added additional configuration information @JohnHanley 
 Thanks & let me know if I can provide anything else that might help you help me!

Comment: Where are the logs showing the termination of the container? You posted only part of the code, show everything to reproduce the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to find that logging information as the only logs I have are above. It shows a GET and the gunicorn output. It's increasingly clear that Cloud Run won't support a background job like I am trying to achieve. I will try my hand at GKE. Thank you

Comment: have you tried setting the timeout to 0 for gunicorn so the instance can be handled by  Cloud Run?
`CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app`

I tried running some of background workers and it worked, although those weren't with `rq` 
Can you post all the configuration that you're following? Like how did you installed the `rq` binay and your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: I was attempting with `--timeout 0` and it _did_ work, to be clear. The problem is that it appears that no matter what settings are toggled, instances are killed after 15 minutes. The only way to prevent this is to block the thread and not return an HTTP response until the work is complete. This still only raises the limit to 60 minutes i.e. the highest request timeout allowed by Cloud Run. In the end, I've opted to run my workers on Compute Engine for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2023-11 Update:**

Google now supports this type of workflow with Cloud Run Jobs without the need to run an HTTP server. You may run a container until it exits for up to [24 hours](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/task-timeout) with [custom parameters / arguments](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs#override-job-configuration).

Jobs docs:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/execute/jobs

---

*Previous answer:*

Using `gunicorn --timeout 0` and blocking the thread to avoid sending an HTTP response works for up to 60 minutes of processing time (i.e. the highest request timeout allowed by Cloud Run). You must configure this on Cloud Run as the default is 5 minutes.

This is not an ideal solution, though:

> The longer the timeout is, the more likely the connection can be lost due to failures on the client side or the Cloud Run side. When a client re-connects, a new request is initiated and the client isn't guaranteed to connect to the same container instance of the service.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout

Otherwise, GKE or Compute Engine work for this type of workload.

Answer (score 0):

If you set minimum and maximum number of instances to be exactly same then it will not cause problem.
If you don't have same number of instances in min max limit then there may get an instance started for long running job while other instance is also available to receive and satisfy the condition of min instance then after 15 min your instance will be destroyed.
After having same value in min as well as max then there is no instance going up or down.